# How to host .Net Core service in IIS without service being recycled

Tags: wcf, iis, asp.net-core

I have a .Net Core Service with a WCF Relay Endpoint. This service needs to be up and running all the time. I do not want to host it as Windows Service, until I'm 100% sure, it is the only solution.

I tried to setup ApplicationPool with "StartMode=AlwaysRunning", "Idle Time-out (minutes)=20" and set Recycling to "Regular time interval(in minutes)=60" but it did not help. Maybe, it is only working for Asp.Net Apps with global.asax events: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/oct/02/use-iis-application-initialization-for-keeping-aspnet-apps-alive

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: just disable recycling all together.  In IIS (I'm looking in v10), you can right click on an app pool and select "recycling..." and enable/disable the recycling.

Comment: Will try it... and let you know.

Comment: I'm using IIS  8.5 (WS 2012 R2) and I can only set Recycling from Right menu panel using "Recycling..." link while having AppPool selected in the list on the left side. I have unchecked everything in "Recycling...", alghoug my apppool is recycled.